# Securing a Java FX standalone application

Tags: javafx, datasource, jndi

I have created a JavaFX standaone application.
I cannot have it deployed in webserver, as some of the users do not have javafx runtime installed in their system. So, i package the application along with the javafx runtime and send it to them for use.

I am using persistence.xml to connect to the database. The password is saved as a plain text file.
So, i have to secure it.

Can someone please give an example of a standalone application accessing a datasource in application server using JNDI? 
Would this approach allow for container managed connection pool handling?

Comment: Do not open the DB directly to the world, you are in for trouble. *Seriously*. Instead, expose the functionality you want as some kind of service (SOAP, REST, even RMI, if nothing else suits you). Identify the client to the service as you would for a web application.

Comment: I can only second that - and BTW what would be different if you'd deploy it to a webserver and launch it with webstart? - Answer nothing!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. Can u plz share a sample program if any.